# Where are UID/GID of a process from, when not from the process's cred pointer?

Tags: linux-kernel, process, virtual-machine, process-management, privileges

## Circumstances

I'm having a lecture on "Cloud Security" at University, and am currently doing a project on virtual machine introspection.

Goal of my exercise was to escalate privileges of some process to root privileges, which I accomplished by "borrowing" the pointer to `struct cred` from `init`, using *volatility* and *libvmi*. Basically just like some rootkits do, but from one VM to another. I can prove the effect of this method by escalating privileges of some process, which repeatedly tries to write to protected memory. Just like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    echo 1 >> /etc/test
    id
    sleep 2
done
```

This leads to the following output (at the time, when privileges change):

```
# last time permission is denied
./test.sh: line 3: /etc/test: Permission denied
uid=1000(tester) gid=1000(tester)groups=1000(tester),24(cdrom),
25(floppy),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),108(netdev),
111(scanner),115(bluetooth)

# tada, magic

# now I'm root
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

## The Question

So I can prove some process (`bash` in above example) has root privileges now. But when I look at the process using `ps u` or directly via `/proc/$PID`, `UID` and `GID` don't seem to have changed.

Output of `ps -A u | grep 2368`:

Before:

```
# ...
tester    2368  0.0  0.9  23556  4552 pts/2    S+   22:24   0:00 -bash
```

After:

```
# ...
tester    2368  0.0  0.9  23556  4552 pts/2    S+   22:24   0:00 -bash
```

Nothing has changed here.

Also `/proc/$PID/status` hasn't changed:

```
~# cat /proc/2368/status | grep Uid
Uid:    1000    1000    1000    1000
~# cat /proc/2368/status | grep Gid
Gid:    1000    1000    1000    1000
```

So can you explain, *why* they don't change there, and *where* that information came from, when they are not taken from the process's `struct cred`, which has obviously been changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tasks do not have a struct cred.  They have *two* struct cred's:

```
 * A task has two security pointers.  task->real_cred points to the objective
 * context that defines that task's actual details.  The objective part of this
 * context is used whenever that task is acted upon.
 *
 * task->cred points to the subjective context that defines the details of how
 * that task is going to act upon another object.  This may be overridden
 * temporarily to point to another security context, but normally points to the
 * same context as task->real_cred.
```

I checked which one `/proc` shows you, but you can probably guess :-P.

(See fs/proc/, using https://elixir.bootlin.com . The procfs "status" file is defined in fs/proc/base.c.)

Comment: Thats it :) Just for curiosity, how/where did you check?